# NOMP - Undefined string

Tags: javascript, node.js, pool, bitcoin

I've done the instructions given at their github page:
https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal
Now, I'm getting this error when I'm running

```
undefined:1
Frs1QCJ","rewardRecipients":{"RrHHam7hYut6RnawbijVdA7j4nT3R67Eun":1,},"payment
                                                                ^
at Object.parse (native)
at /root/nomp/init.js:102:32
at Array.forEach (native)
at buildPoolConfigs (/root/nomp/init.js:100:31)
at init (/root/nomp/init.js:431:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/nomp/init.js:443:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I tried deleting that "}" and the problems just keep getting bigger. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: {lease post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a extra comma there, that section should be this:

```
Frs1QCJ","rewardRecipients":{"RrHHam7hYut6RnawbijVdA7j4nT3R67Eun":1},"payment
                     There was a comma here, it should be removed--^
```

JSON doesn't allow trailing commas. Even though they work fine in javascript object literals.